# How to plot a 2D plot in MATlab from Three Matrices and an array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, plot

I am trying to plot a figure using three matrices but somehow I couldn't understand. I have three matrices and an array. Suppose,

```
A =

     1     2     3

     4     5     4

     7     8     9

B =

     2     3    13

     5    11    10

     9     7     6


C =

     1     2     3
     2     3    13
     5    11    10
```

and an array

```
Y= [0.001 0.0002 0.0004].
```

Now I want to plot it in such a way that array values should be on y axis while against 0.001, 0.002 and 0.0004 the matrices value should be arranged.
for examples, the `y=0.001, A(1,1)=1, y=0.0002, B(1,1)=2 y=0.0004, C(1,1)=1` for a single line.

and similarly process goes for `A(i,j),B(i,j)` and `c(i,j)` points using loop to plot all lines on a single figure.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is very confusing. Can you try to rephrase it, please?

Comment: @AnderBiguri I have three matrices and an array as shown above. Now I want to plot it in a way that these three values of an array (0.001, 0.0002, 0.0004) should be on the y-axis and on the x-axis, first value of matrix A should be plotted against 0.001 value of array and first value of matrix B should be plotted against second value of array which is 0.0002 and similarly for third value.

Comment: I don't understand. What does i,j stand for? axes x,y? Do you want to plot all values of A against 0.001, all values of B against 0.0002 and all values of C in 0.0004? And then connect all (i,j) pairs?

Comment: @ana, yes. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: I think @Florian's answer is just that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the first plot is `plot([1,2,1],Y)`, the next one is `plot([2,3,2],Y)` and so on?

If so, you could do it like that

```
X = cat(3,cat(3,A,B),C);
X = reshape(permute(X,[3,1,2]),3,9);
plot(X,Y,'--x');
```

which gives a plot like this:

[image: Resulting plot]

Is this what you were looking for? If not, I didn't understand your question well and I'd like to ask you to rephrase it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a 3D array (tensor) and access it in a loop.

```
T(:,:,1) = A;
T(:,:,2) = B;
T(:,:,3) = C;

figure;
for idi = 1:size(A,1)
    for idj = 1:size(A,2)
        plot(squeeze(T(idi,idj,:)).',Y); hold on;
    end
end
```

Accessing the third dimension is not fastest operation (as they are not store sequential in memory) and if the matrices are larger you might consider `reshape`.

I did not understand you wanted the vector `Y` to be on the x-axis or y-axis (and neither of those plots make sense to me) but I am sure you can modify the code from here for your needs.